# javascript regex innermost parentheses not surrounded by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a JS regular expression that will find the innermost parentheses that is not surrounded by quotes. Parentheses can be nested infinitely.

**Example 1:**

`(This should not match (This will match "(with this)" intact), but will exclude this and (this))`

So, in the example the result would be `This will match "(with this)" intact`

**Example 2:**

`(This should not match (This will match with this intact), but will exclude this and (this))`

So, in the example the result would be `This will match with this intact`

I tried `/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/` which gives me the innermost parentheses, but does not escape the quotes.

Comment: 1) Please put your attempt in the question. 2) Javascript regex doesn't like nesting stuff. You'd probably be better off with a specific parser.

Comment: There is no regex recursion in JS. You can use regex to tokenize but parse it some other way.

Comment: You're describing a context-free grammar. Regex is the wrong tool for parsing such things; in fact, it's impossible with pure regex. You should use a true parser for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind stripping off the outer parenthesis yourself

```
/\([^()"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^()"]*)*\)/
```

gives me `(This will match "(with this)" intact)` on the first example input and `(This will match with this intact)` on the second example.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost there, but it will not match example 2 I just added :(

Comment: I've updated the regular expression so it matches the second as well (I should have anticipated that there doesn't _have to be_ a quoted string, silly, that)

Comment: So, there is no way to capture what's in between the matching parentheses? You mention that I'd have to strip outer parentheses, but I was hoping to have match like current, but also have a capture group for content (e.g. `This will match "(with this)" intact`)

Comment: Yeah, you can put parenthesis around the part you want, so `/\(([^()"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^()"]*)*)\)/`. The captured group will be the second element in the array returned by `.match()`. I should also mention it finds the first one, not necessarily the longest one (you'd have to loop over all matches and compare the lengths yourself if you want that.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible alternative :

```
/\(((?:"\(|\)"|[^()])+)\)/
```

Usage example :

```
'( (a"(b)") )'.match(/\(((?:"\(|\)"|[^()])+)\)/) // ["(a"(b)")", "a"(b)""]
```

Description :

```
"\(|\)"|[^()]   "( or )" or any char except parenthesis
((?:...)+)      one or more times (capture -> group 1)
\(...\)         enclosed in a pair of parenthesis
```

Comment: That also matches `'("()'`, because there's no check for matching double quotes.

Comment: @towr There is nothing about this kind of input in the question but well, here is a fix : `/\(((?:"\([^()]+\)"|[^()])+)?\)/`.